# Ant build.xml not functioning properly

Tags: ant, build.xml

Below is a simplified versin of a build.xml for a Java project. It completes "build" correctly (creates the correct .class files) and prints out "Finishing build". It does not, however, print out "Starting jar". What am I not understanding? The target "jar" depends on "build", so it should be run next.

Running it with target release.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Project" basedir="." default="release">

    <!-- directories -->
    <property name="src.dir" location="src/main/java"/>
    <property name="cls.dir" location="private/classes"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" location="lib"/>

    <property name="jar.name" value="${ant.project.name}-${jar.ver}.jar"/>

    <target name="clean" description="Delete all generated files">
        <delete dir="${cls.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${lib.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${cls.dir}"/>
        <javac
            destdir="${cls.dir}"
            nowarn="off"
            fork="yes"
            debug="on">
            <classpath>
                <path path="${run.classpath}"/>
            </classpath>
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
        </javac>
        <echo message="Finishing build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="build">
        <echo message="Starting jar"/>
        <mkdir dir="${lib.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${lib.dir}/${jar.name}">
            <fileset dir="${cls.dir}"/>
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.properties"/>
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.xml"/>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="release" depends="jar" description="Entry point">
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: What is the command you use when running the target? Are you running the jar target?

Comment: Running with release, the jar part does not run. If I run w/ jar, then jar also runs. I want jar to run when I run with release..

Comment: Try running with "ant -v" for verbose output and see if that gives you a clue.

Comment: Run the command `ant -d release`. You may want to redirect that output to a file. The start will show you the calculation it does to figure out the dependency matrix. By the way, you should not have your `build` depend upon `clean`. You can have `release` depend upon `clean,jar`, but you want developers to be able to do a build without wiping out all class files that were built`.

Answer (score 0):

Update the release target as follows to note that release depends on build then jar. i.e. depends="build,jar"
i.e.

```
    <target name="release" depends="build,jar" description="Entry point">
       <echo message="release ..."/>
    </target>
```

Comment: This made no difference at all.

Comment: This works. Tried it an ran. Can you clarify the following. What version of ant? Are you running on commandline or in IDE? how are you executing the run target? Lastly have you tried running with ant -v to print detailed output? Can you post the output for review? These details might better help diagnose your problem, but your ant file is ok? It is some other issue. Also before running, can you ran clean separately and validate that the old build is deleted before running any other targets